# Continuation passing style code in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, functional-programming, objective-c-blocks, continuation-passing

Can we write Continuation passing style code in Objective C?
If yes, could you please give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuation Passing Style, or CPS, is a style of programming using anonymous functions to replace return statements. Instead of returning a value, a function will take another function as a parameter. Then, when it gets to the point where it would have returned a value, it calls the passed-in function with the value as a parameter instead.

In Objective-C, we now have anonymous functions in the form of blocks, so CPS can be achieved using blocks.

Here's an example of how CPS looks. This is the standard-style code:

```
NSString *string = [obj stringWhatever];
    // use string
```

And here it is converted to Continuation Passing Style:

```
[obj stringWhatever: ^(NSString *string) {
    // use string
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give an example on how to pass a block to another block? BTW, is it possible to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: this will help you https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-05-error-returns-with-continuation-passing-style.html

Comment: I try to use this code, but it doesn't work..Here is my code:   NSDate *obj = [NSDate date];
        [obj description: ^(NSString *s) {
            NSLog(@"%@",s);
        }];

Comment: @KunHu You can't just arbitrarily take any random method and turn it into a continuation method.   `stringWhatever` and `stringWhatever:` are **two different methods** with different implementation semantics.

Comment: @bbum Could you please post an answer for more details? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @KunHu Are you familiar with CPS in other languages? It works exactly the same. If you need an introduction to Objective-C, there are plenty of books.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm new with CPS, I've only seen some code in Python. I am comfortable with Objective-C, but not familiar with the blocks.

Comment: @KunHu [This](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-05-error-returns-with-continuation-passing-style.html) looks like a decent crash-course in Objective-C (didn't read it thoroughly). CPS is more common in languages like ML/Haskell/Scheme, so the literature is richer there.